# An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. (argparse error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, argparse

I am trying to run https://github.com/haqishen/Google-Landmark-Recognition-2020-3rd-Place-Solution
(train.py)

- code

  ```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--kernel-type', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--data-dir', type=str, default='/raid/GLD2')
    parser.add_argument('--train-step', type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--image-size', type=int, required=True)
    parser.add_argument("--local_rank", type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--enet-type', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--batch-size', type=int, default=64)
    parser.add_argument('--num-workers', type=int, default=32)
    parser.add_argument('--init-lr', type=float, default=1e-4)
    parser.add_argument('--n-epochs', type=int, default=15)
    parser.add_argument('--start-from-epoch', type=int, default=1)
    parser.add_argument('--stop-at-epoch', type=int, default=999)
    parser.add_argument('--use-amp', action='store_false')
    parser.add_argument('--DEBUG', action='store_true')
    parser.add_argument('--model-dir', type=str, default='./weights')
    parser.add_argument('--log-dir', type=str, default='./logs')
    parser.add_argument('--CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES', type=str, default='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7')
    parser.add_argument('--fold', type=int, default=0)
    parser.add_argument('--load-from', type=str, default='')

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
  ```
- error message

  ```
    usage:  [-h] --kernel-type KERNEL_TYPE [--data-dir DATA_DIR] --train-step
    TRAIN_STEP --image-size IMAGE_SIZE [--local_rank LOCAL_RANK]
    --enet-type ENET_TYPE [--batch-size BATCH_SIZE]
    [--num-workers NUM_WORKERS] [--init-lr INIT_LR] [--n-epochs N_EPOCHS]
    [--start-from-epoch START_FROM_EPOCH] [--stop-at-epoch STOP_AT_EPOCH]
    [--use-amp] [--DEBUG] [--model-dir MODEL_DIR] [--log-dir LOG_DIR]
    [--CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES] [--fold FOLD]
    [--load-from LOAD_FROM]
    : error: the following arguments are required: --kernel-type, --train-step, --image-size, --enet-type

    An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

    SystemExit: 2
  ```

I've seen that some people already had this problem when trying to use arg_parse, but I can't find an easy solution.

How I can fix it? Help me...

Comment: How are you running the script?  Are you including the `--kernel-type`, `--train-step`, `--image-size`, and `--enet-type` args as the message suggests?

Comment: looks like you using ipython or jupyter notebook.  That's what the %tb error capture suggests.  Anyways your calling method has not provided the required parameters (as specified by the arparse setup)

Comment: The github examples all start with:  `python -u -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=6 train.py --kernel-type b7ns_DDP_final_256_300w_f0_10ep --train-step 0 --data-dir ${data_dir} ...`.  Those are run from the (Linux) shell, using `python`.  That's how you should run your code, not via a `ipython` or `notebook` (unless you know what you are doing).